# How to modify file permissions to prevent deletion but enable execution?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a few important files that may be accessed by someone with next to no knowledge of Ubuntu, and he might delete some of those unconsciously.
The files need to be kept executable, I thought of chattr +i command to do the job but that also removes execution permission? It would help if there's no write permission on the file as well but not really bothered by that

Comment: File permissions can prevent someone from overwriting the file, but do not prevent deletion.  The ability to remove the file from the directory (aka "delete the file") is controlled by permissions on the directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities !

1. If all colleague uses same user to access in Ubuntu system.
   If this is happening,
   You can set executable permission and set immutable attribute for this.
2. If Ubuntu Administrator provide different user to login in Ubuntu system.
   If this,
   You can put that script under directory and set sticky bit to that directory.